# How can I download or clone my bitbucket server via c# rest-api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, bitbucket

I want to download bitbucket repository via c# rest-api. I have project name, project key, repo_slug. I use bitbucket api 1.0. How can I download the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using https://github.com/MitjaBezensek/SharpBucket as a base rather than reinventing the wheel. SharpBucket is a .Net wrapper for the Bitbucket's REST API. It is written in in C#.

It has most of the functionality that you have requested.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed like this


var co = new CloneOptions();
co.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials { Username = username, Password = password };

LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(url_2, path, co);